# SQL select statement timeout expired

Tags: sql, select, timeout

We have a regular select statement

```
strSql = "SELECT PG_ID, PG_FileName, PG_AbsolutePath " & _
             "FROM PHOTO_GALLERY " & _
             "WHERE (PG_ID = " & lPG_ID & ")"
```

in SQL Analyzer it works good and quick, on the page, the duration I get from the profiler is more the 7000 and then I get to the error log we have built, timeout expired

The table photo_gallery has just a bit more than 8000 rows

What can be done in order to find the solution for that?

The table has an index on `PG_ID`

The variable `lPG_ID` is not null - it is a number and it is there in the rows of the table

Comment: Are you sure it's this query that is causing the timeout?

Comment: If `PG_ID` is indexed, it can't get much faster. Are you sure the timeout derives from the SQL statement and nothing else (p.e. script where the SQL statement is included, network connection to the sql server)?

Comment: Don't see anything wrong with the query. Could you post it without other languages impurity?

Comment: @nemoden: well, concatenating together your SQL statements is always wrong - it's prone to SQL injection attacks. You should always use parametrized queries instead....

Comment: @marc_s: the lPG_ID is part of a function inside another check for sql injections. the code i gave here is part of our CMS and it is an old website that one part of it didn't work.

Comment: @marc_s thank you but I don't need somebody to teach me about `SQL` injections :) I was interested to see the exact `SQL` from the **OP** no more no less

Answer (score -1):

Before Executing your query

```
Set

SqlClient.SqlCommand.CommandTimeout = 0
```

Will Resolved Your issue....